# I am trying to implement elastic search with firebase cloud functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, elasticsearch, google-cloud-functions

Here is my code:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const {Client} = require("@elastic/elasticsearch");

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const env = functions.config();

const auth = {
  username: env.elasticsearch.username,
  password: env.elasticsearch.password,
};

const client = new Client({
  node: env.elasticsearch.url,
  auth: auth,
});

exports.createTest = functions.firestore
    .document("tests/{testId}")
    .onCreate( async (snap, context) => {
        await client.index({
            index: "temp",
            type: "_doc",
            id: snap.id,
            body: snap.data(),
        })
    });
```

but I am getting the following error.

```
createTest
ResponseError: {"statusCode":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"Not Found"} at SniffingTransport.request (/workspace/node_modules/@elastic/transport/lib/Transport.js:476:27) at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) at async Client.IndexApi [as index] (/workspace/node_modules/@elastic/elasticsearch/lib/api/api/index.js:51:12) at async /workspace/index.js:22:9
```

Comment: is index with name `temp` available in Elasticsearch ? You can check from Kibana using `GET temp` command or from browser using `localhost:9200/temp` (if your elastic running on local and 9200 port)

Comment: Basically I am having an issue with firebase and elastic search connection

Comment: and I cant find temp index in elastic search using GET temp

Comment: It gives index not found error

Comment: use `PUT temp` command from kibana and try it out.